# Cannot start Rviz in ROS launch file

Tags: ros

I'm fairly new to ROS system. Every time I wanna start a Rviz node in launch file, it always said `cannot launch node of type [rviz/rviz]: Cannot launch node of type [rviz] in package [rviz]. Make sure file exists in package path and permission is set to executable`. However, I can easily start Rviz by using `rviz` or `rosrun rviz rviz` in terminal. Does anyone know what's going on here? Thank you!

Comment: Could you please provide your launch file as well?

Comment: No one can answer this question without seeing your launch file. Although given how the error looks it would appear you haven't source'd the correct `setup.bash` file

Comment: My launch file is like:
`<launch>
      <node name="rviz" pkg="rviz" type="rviz"/>
</launch>`

Answer (score 0):

To launch rviz add the following line in your launch file:

```xml
<!--launch rviz-->
<node name="rviz" pkg="rviz" type="rviz" respawn="false" args="-d $(find bot_name)/default.rviz"/>
```

You can also save your settings in default.rviz

Note: Change the name for your bot in the line specified above